# Query Optimization with WHERE condition and a single JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I have 2 tables with `one-to-many` relationship.

- Users-> 1 million (1)
- Requests-> 10 millions (n)

What I'm trying to do, is to fetch the user alongside with the latest `request` made; and be able to filter the whole dataset based on the (last) `request` columns.

The current query is fetching the correct results but it is painfully slow. ~7-9 seconds

```
SELECT *
FROM users AS u
         INNER JOIN requests AS r
                    ON u.id = r.user_id
WHERE (r.created_at = u.last_request_date AND r.ignored = false)
ORDER BY u.last_request_date DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

I have also tried to `JOIN` the `r.created_at` as a second `ON` condition instead of filtering on the `WHERE` statement, but without a difference in performance.

UPDATE:

Indexes:

- Users: last_request_date
- Requests: created_at, user_id(foreign)

Execution plan: https://explain.depesz.com/s/JsLr#source

```
Execution plan:
    Limit  (cost=1000.88..21080.19 rows=10 width=139) (actual time=15966.670..15990.322 rows=10 loops=1)
      Buffers: shared hit=3962420 read=152361
      ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1000.88..757990.77 rows=377 width=139) (actual time=15966.653..15990.138 rows=10 loops=1)
            Workers Planned: 2
            Workers Launched: 2
            Buffers: shared hit=3962420 read=152361
            ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.86..756947.24 rows=157 width=139) (actual time=9456.384..10622.180 rows=7 loops=3)
                  Buffers: shared hit=3962420 read=152361
    "              ->  Parallel Index Scan Backward using users_last_request_date on users ""User""  (cost=0.42..55742.72 rows=420832 width=75) (actual time=0.061..2443.484 rows=333340 loops=3)"
                        Buffers: shared hit=5102 read=15849
                  ->  Index Scan using requests_user_id on requests  (cost=0.43..1.66 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=0 loops=1000019)
    "                    Index Cond: (user_id = ""User"".id)"
    "                    Filter: ((NOT ignored) AND (""User"".last_request_date = created_at))"
                        Rows Removed by Filter: 10
                        Buffers: shared hit=3957318 read=136512
    Planning Time: 0.745 ms
    Execution Time: 15990.489 ms
```

Comment: Performace depends on your indexes, could you show us your execution plan & indexes from your table?

Comment: When 'a lot of' your records have another value than `r.ignored=false`, then an index on `r.created_at` will not be of much use.

Comment: @D-Shih I have updated my question

Comment: 1. Users needs one index on both id and last_request_date (join clause is a double lookup).  2. Do you *Really* need all columns from both users and requests?  Trim it to just those you need.  3. Try Order By r.created_at instead.  They are both equivalent

Comment: Don't use `*` all if you're interested in performance. Name the columns that you need.

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We need row counts because that can affect query planning. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating this BTREE index to handle the requests table lookup more efficiently.

```
CREATE INDEX id_ignored_date ON requests (user_id, ignored, created_at);
```

Your plan says

```
->  Index Scan using requests_user_id on requests 
       (cost=0.43..1.66 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=0 loops=1000019)
    "Index Cond: (user_id = ""User"".id)"
    "Filter: ((NOT ignored) AND (""User"".last_request_date = created_at))"
```

and this index will move the Filter conditions into the Index Cond, which should be faster.

**Pro tip:** @Kendle is right. Don't use `SELECT *` in production software, especially performance-sensitive software, unless you have a good reason. It makes your RDBMS server, network, and client program work harder for no good reason.

**Edit**: Read this about how to use multicolumn BTREE indexes effectively. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-multicolumn.html

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. I have asked the same question on an answer above as well.  I'm having 3 more columns on requests tables which can be filtered like the "ignored" column. Any suggestion on this?

Comment: You can try adding the other filter columns to the multicolumn index.

Answer (score 1):

As you only need the last 10 users I would suggest that we only fetch the last 100 records from requests. This may avoid a million join comparisons, to test as the query optimiser may already be doing this.
This number should be modified according to your application. It may be that the last 10 records will always be 10 different users or that we need to fetch more than 100 to be sure of having 10 users.

```
SELECT *
FROM users AS u
         INNER JOIN (select * from requests
                    where r.ignored = false
                    order by created_at desc
                    limit 100) AS r
                    ON u.id = r.user_id
WHERE (r.created_at = u.last_request_date)
ORDER BY u.last_request_date DESC
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

Answer (score 1):

The biggest bottleneck from your execution plan was this part, `requests` might add one more column `created_at` to the index (because there is a filter cost)

```
->  Index Scan using requests_user_id on requests  (cost=0.43..1.66 rows=1 width=64) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=0 loops=1000019)
"                    Index Cond: (user_id = ""User"".id)"
"                    Filter: ((NOT ignored) AND (""User"".last_request_date = created_at))"
    Rows Removed by Filter: 10
    Buffers: shared hit=3957318 read=136512
```

so you might try to create an index like the below.

```
CREATE INDEX IX_requests ON requests (
   user_id,
   created_at 
);
```

If the `ignored = false` is a small amount on the `requests` table you can try to use [Partial Indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html) which might help you reduce your storage and improve your index performance.

```
CREATE INDEX FIX_requests ON requests (
   user_id,
   created_at 
)
WHERE ignored = false;
```

On the other thing, I would use an index as below for `users` table because there is an order by on the `last_request_date` column and `users` table join `request` table by `id`

```
CREATE INDEX IX_users ON users (
   last_request_date,
   id 
);
```

**NOTE**

I would avoid using `SELECT *` because it might cost more than `IO` we might not need use select all columns from the table in most scenes.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. A question please. I'm having 3 more columns on requests tables which can be filtered like the "ignored". Any suggestion on this?

Comment: If you might want to filter those columns you can try to add them to be multicolumn index.